# Do I need to have two queues for Service Broker?

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

I am just starting with Service Broker and looking at the examples in blogs, most have a sending and receiving service with separate queues.

Looking at the SEND TO command (to send a message) I need to reference a CONVERSATION. And it seems that a CONVERSATION has FROM SERVICE and TO SERVICE parameters.

Is it wrong or bad design to send from/to the same service, with a single queue? I tried it and it seems to work.

My SQL table will have code in a trigger to send a simple empty message. This will notify a SignalR client that the table has changed, and send out new data. For such an application, surely a single queue and single service is okay?

Comment: If you are starting out with Service Broker I highly recommend this book "Pro SQL Server 2008 Service Broker"  https://wordery.com/pro-sql-server-2008-service-broker-klaus-aschenbrenner-9781430243021

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have to, but is a good practice.

You must be aware that your 'from' service will also get messages in it's queue, even if you never send any. There are system messages, most obvious ones being the EndDialog and Error messages. You have to handle at least those. So your code that services the queue must be able to properly handle the messages sent to the initiator (the 'from' service). With a single queue for both services you will get a mix of messages, some for initiator some for target.

> will have code in a trigger to send a simple empty message

Make sure you do not do [Fire and Forget](http://rusanu.com/2006/04/06/fire-and-forget-good-for-the-military-but-not-for-service-broker-conversations/), read [How to prevent conversation endpoint leaks](http://rusanu.com/2014/03/31/how-to-prevent-conversation-endpoint-leaks/) to understand why is important.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I had not come across the Fire and Forget issue so far. That said the sender doesn't need to know if the message was read or not, so it may be appropriate.

Comment: Having read more it seems like Service Broker is far more complicated than I need for such a simple service. I'll investigate alternatives.. thanks